# Sort list of names and scores in Python 3

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of data that is in the structure of name and then score like this:

```
['Danny', '8', 'John', '5', 'Sandra', 10]
```

What I require to do in the simplest way possible is sort the data by lowest to highest score for example like this:

```
['John', '5', 'Danny', '8', 'Sandra', 10]
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend structuring your data so names and scores are grouped together in tuples, like `[('Danny', 8), ('John', 5), ('Sandra', 10)]`. Also ensure your scores are numbers, not strings, for accurate results.

Comment: Create mappings between user and score

Answer (score 2):

You should create pairings which will make your life a lot easier:

```
l = ['Danny', '8', 'John', '5', 'Sandra', '10']


it = iter(l)


srt = sorted(zip(it, it), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Which will give you:

```
[('John', '5'), ('Danny', '8'), ('Sandra', '10')]
```

`it = iter(l)` creates an iterator, then `zip(it, it)` basically  calls `(next(it), next(it))` each iteration so you create pairs of tuples in the format `(user, score)`, then we sort by the  second element of each tuple which is the score, casting to int.

You may be as well to cast to int and then sortif you plan on using the data, you could also create a flat list from the sorted data but I think that would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The best data structure for your problem is [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

In your situatiton you need to map between names and scores.

```
dict  = {'Danny':'8', 'John':'5', 'Sandra':'10'}

sorted_dict = ((k, dict[k]) for k in sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=False))

for k, v in genexp:
...     k, v

('John', '5')
('Danny', '8')
('Sandra', 10)
```